# How can I make OS X Stickies *custom* colors?

Tags: macos, stickies

OS X Stickies lets you change the background color of a stickie note to any of six colors.  How can I select a different, custom color for my notes?

I don't see any preferences that allow me to do this.  So, I was hoping to simply edit some file contained in the Stickies.app bundle, or in the StickiesDatabase.  But, I can't find the right spot to edit.  I determined that the blue note has color #ADF4FF, in hopes that I'd be able to find that hex string in some file and replace it with the hex code of another color, but no matter which file I opened in HexEdit, I could not find "ADF4FF" in the hex contents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The color values are hard-coded in the `Stickies` binary.

Decompile and look in `StickiesWindow setColorByIndex:`. The colors are created using `NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:green:blue:alpha:`.

Comment: How do you decompile Mac apps to get to the level of code?

Comment: @Nano8Blazex `otool` is included with the developer tools. You don't actually get the code though.

Comment: To be honest, it seems they use array elements for arguments to that function call, from the little assembly I can read, so the colors could be defined elsewhere. It's just that html color syntax won't help the user in finding that.